# Regular Expressions slowing down the program

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm trying to create a program that parses data from game's chat log. So far I have managed to get the program to work and parse the data that I want but my problem is that the program is getting slower.

Currently it takes 5 seconds to parse a 10MB text file and I noticed it drops down to 3 seconds if I add RegexOptions.Compiled to my regex.

I believe I have pinpointed the problem to my regex matches. One line is currently read 5 times because of the 5 regexes so the program would get even slower when I add more later.

What should I do so my program would not slow down with multiple regexes? All suggestions to make the code better are appreciated!

```
if (sender.Equals(ButtonParse))
        {
            var totalShots = 0f;
            var totalHits = 0f;
            var misses = 0;
            var crits = 0;

            var regDmg = new Regex(@"(?<=\bSystem\b.* You inflicted )\d+.\d", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var regMiss = new Regex(@"(?<=\bSystem\b.* Target evaded attack)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var regCrit = new Regex(@"(?<=\bSystem\b.* Critical hit - additional damage)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var regHeal = new Regex(@"(?<=\bSystem\b.* You healed yourself )\d+.\d", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var regDmgrec = new Regex(@"(?<=\bSystem\b.* You take )\d+.\d", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            var dmgList = new List<float>(); //New list for damage values
            var healList = new List<float>(); //New list for heal values
            var dmgRecList = new List<float>(); //New list for damage received values

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();

                    var match = regDmg.Match(line);
                    var match2 = regMiss.Match(line);
                    var match3 = regCrit.Match(line);
                    var match4 = regHeal.Match(line);
                    var match5 = regDmgrec.Match(line);

                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        dmgList.Add(float.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                        totalShots++;
                        totalHits++;
                    }
                    if (match2.Success)
                    {
                        misses++;
                        totalShots++;
                    }
                    if (match3.Success)
                    {
                        crits++;
                    }
                    if (match4.Success)
                    {
                        healList.Add(float.Parse(match4.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                    if (match5.Success)
                    {
                        dmgRecList.Add(float.Parse(match5.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                }
                TextBlockTotalShots.Text = totalShots.ToString(); //Show total shots
                TextBlockTotalDmg.Text = dmgList.Sum().ToString("0.##"); //Show total damage inflicted

                TextBlockTotalHits.Text = totalHits.ToString(); //Show total hits
                var hitChance = totalHits / totalShots; //Calculate hit chance
                TextBlockHitChance.Text = hitChance.ToString("P"); //Show hit chance

                TextBlockTotalMiss.Text = misses.ToString(); //Show total misses
                var missChance = misses / totalShots; //Calculate miss chance
                TextBlockMissChance.Text = missChance.ToString("P"); //Show miss chance

                TextBlockTotalCrits.Text = crits.ToString(); //Show total crits
                var critChance = crits / totalShots; //Calculate crit chance
                TextBlockCritChance.Text = critChance.ToString("P"); //Show crit chance

                TextBlockDmgHealed.Text = healList.Sum().ToString("F1"); //Show damage healed

                TextBlockDmgReceived.Text = dmgRecList.Sum().ToString("F1"); //Show damage received

                var pedSpent = dmgList.Sum() / (float.Parse(TextBoxEco.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 100); //Calculate ped spent
                TextBlockPedSpent.Text = pedSpent.ToString("0.##") + " PED"; //Estimated ped spent
            }
        }
```

And here's a sample text:

```
2014-09-02 23:07:22 [System] [] You inflicted 45.2 points of damage.
2014-09-02 23:07:23 [System] [] You inflicted 45.4 points of damage.
2014-09-02 23:07:24 [System] [] Target evaded attack.
2014-09-02 23:07:25 [System] [] You inflicted 48.4 points of damage.
2014-09-02 23:07:26 [System] [] You inflicted 48.6 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:39:55 [System] [] Target evaded attack.
2014-10-15 12:39:58 [System] [] You inflicted 56.0 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:39:59 [System] [] You inflicted 74.6 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:02 [System] [] You inflicted 78.6 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:04 [System] [] Target evaded attack.
2014-10-15 12:40:06 [System] [] You inflicted 66.9 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:08 [System] [] You inflicted 76.2 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:12 [System] [] You take 18.4 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:14 [System] [] You inflicted 76.1 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:17 [System] [] You inflicted 88.5 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:19 [System] [] You inflicted 69.0 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:56:30 [System] [] Critical hit - additional damage! You inflict 275.4 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:29 [System] [] You inflicted 92.8 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:31 [System] [] Critical hit - additional damage! You inflict 251.5 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:35 [System] [] You take 59.4 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:39 [System] [] You healed yourself 84.0 points.
```

Comment: Don't use lookarounds (variable length lookbehinds, ie `(?<=...)`), instead use capturing groups `(...)` to get the values you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much Qtax! I had no idea of the performance hit lookbehind did and now I learned about grouping. Now it takes less than a second to process the whole thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the issues as I see it

1. As suggested in the comments don't have the regex parser working way too much for a basic pattern situations.
2. Why parse the data multiple times on the same text? Create one regex pattern to do all the work with one scan over each line.
3. In WPF don't hold up the GUI thread to do work, do the work in a background task and update a viewmodel (you are using MVVM right?) which will propagate the info to the screen using INotifyPropertyChanged events.

The following is a one regex pattern solution which works on a line by line basis. Its first task is to verify that `[System]` is contained on the line. If it is not, it does no matching on that line. If it does have system, then it looks for specific keywords and possible values and places them into regex `named match captures` in a key/value pair situation.

Once that is done using linq it will sum up the values found. Note that I have commented the pattern and had the regex parser ignore it.

```
string pattern = @"^       # Beginning of line to anchor it.
(?=.+\[System\])           # Within the line a literal '[System]' has to occur
(?=.+                      # Somewhere within that line search for these keywords:
  (?<Action>               # Named Match Capture Group 'Action' will hold a keyword.
          inflicte?d?      # if the line has inflict or inflicted put it into 'Action'
          |                # or
          evaded           # evaded
          | take           # or take
          | yourself       # or yourself (heal)
   )
  (\s(?<Value>[\d.]+))?)   # if a value of points exist place into 'Value'
.+                         # match one or more to complete it.
$                          #end of line to stop on";

 // IgnorePatternWhiteSpace only allows us to comment the pattern. Does not affect processing.
var tokens =
   Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline)
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select( mt => new {
                            Action = mt.Groups["Action"].Value,
                            Value  = mt.Groups["Value"].Success ? double.Parse(mt.Groups["Value"].Value) : 0,
                            Count  = 1,
                           })
         .GroupBy ( itm => itm.Action,  // Each action will be grouped into its name for summing
                    itm => itm,   // This is value to summed amongst the individual items of the group.
                    (action, values) => new
                            {
                                Action = action,
                                Count  = values.Sum (itm => itm.Count),
                                Total  = values.Sum(itm => itm.Value)
                             }
                         );
```

### Result

The linq result returns each of the tokens as an entity which sums up all the values for the actions, but also counts up the number of times those actions occurred.

[image]

### DATA

```
string data=@"2014-09-02 23:07:22 [System] [] You inflicted 45.2 points of damage.
2014-09-02 23:07:23 [System] [] You inflicted 45.4 points of damage.
2014-09-02 23:07:24 [System] [] Target evaded attack.
2014-09-02 23:07:25 [System] [] You inflicted 48.4 points of damage.
2014-09-02 23:07:26 [System] [] You inflicted 48.6 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:39:55 [System] [] Target evaded attack.
2014-10-15 12:39:58 [System] [] You inflicted 56.0 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:39:59 [System] [] You inflicted 74.6 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:02 [System] [] You inflicted 78.6 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:04 [System] [] Target evaded attack.
2014-10-15 12:40:06 [System] [] You inflicted 66.9 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:08 [System] [] You inflicted 76.2 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:12 [System] [] You take 18.4 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:14 [System] [] You inflicted 76.1 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:17 [System] [] You inflicted 88.5 points of damage.
2014-10-15 12:40:19 [System] [] You inflicted 69.0 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:56:30 [System] [] Critical hit - additional damage! You inflict 275.4 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:29 [System] [] You inflicted 92.8 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:31 [System] [] Critical hit - additional damage! You inflict 251.5 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:35 [System] [] You take 59.4 points of damage.
2014-10-19 05:59:39 [System] [] You healed yourself 84.0 points.";
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the regex pattern. I tried doing something similar but I lack the skill but now I'm learning. I implemented this in my program but I have 2 problems with it. Firstly, this works fine with the sample data, but with actual log it gives me the error "Input string was not in a correct format." Secondly, I got it to work after leaving in only evade and critical datas but the program now takes 10 seconds to process the data.

Comment: @nhahtdh I agree that the pattern can be further modified to weed out the unnecessary parts to speed it up. That was my first attempt so there is likely a better pattern. I have that part at the beginning (the `^`) and to match but don't capture `(?:  )`, or eat up the beginning to one of the true matches the user is looking to find. That section *anchors* it to each line for a match. But I agree it could be changed at some point to just look for specific word matches without the beginning of the line anchor.

Comment: I suggest dropping the whole thing, since the keywords makes better anchor than having the `.+` part.

Comment: @nhahtdh I should have pointed out that I need to check that the message comes from [System] and nowhere else. As the log also contains chat data, if player types these words, I get inaccurate data as it doesn't come from [System]. Anyway, as Qtax commented on my question, lookbehinds had a huge performance hit in my program and removing them fixed the issue but feel free to answer if you know even better way dealing with this.

Comment: @Iceyou90 I updated my regex to verify it only gets system lines, but changed the logic to put each of the items into key value pairs which could be summed up. As mentioned in the new post, since this is WPF don't do any processing on the GUI thread, place the operation in a background thread/task as to not interrupt the user.